# Is it possible to get the global scale of a Widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Consider this code:

```
Transform.scale(scale: .5, child:
      Transform.scale(scale: .5, child: 
         _MyBox()));
```

Is there any way that `MyBox` can access it's resulting scale factor of **0.25**, internally with it's own context?

In Unity this would be `rectTransform.scale`(.25) and `rectTransform.localScale`(.5). With Flash we could just walk up the displayList with `.parent` and calculate it ourselves. Any equivalent in Flutter?

[Edit] The answer seem to be:

```
RenderBox rb = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
if (rb != null) {
  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    // Should return you the final scale of this context 
    print(rb.getTransformTo(null));
  });
}
```

Comment: `RenderObject.getTransformTo` ?

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work, though it is a bit flaky. It throws an assertion error if I try and get the scale inside of build, so I have to wrap it in a scheduleMicrotask, I also need to cause the build to run twice, since findRenderBox returns null initially.

Comment: hmm, you could try `RenderObject.applyPaintTransform` too, but i wouldnt expect better results